# Can the elements that make up an object be separated and organised by element?

Tags: thermodynamics

Is there a way to separate an object into the atoms it's made of, and then organise the resulting atoms by type?

For example a lightbulb would split into the silicon and oxygen that the glass was made of, copper and zinc from the brass casing and wires.

Maybe [fractional distillation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_distillation) after heating the object (probably requires vast heat)? Or multiple processes to split certain elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what a [mass spectrometer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_spectrometry) does. You vaporize/ionize a substance into its smallest constituents, ionize the individual atoms (or larger fragments... depends on how you break things up), accelerate them to a certain energy (with an electric field), focus them, and deflect them with a magnetic field. The amount of deflection you get will depend on the charge on the particle (single ionization, double ionization, ...) and its mass. Detecting the intensity of the current of ions as a function of angle gives you almost exactly what you asked for. "fractional distillation for atoms".

Just ask Abby from NCIS. Her "friend", "Major Mass Spec", does this for a living.